# WordPress images and pages broken after host migration

Tags: wordpress

I have created a WordPress site (my first) but since moving the site to a new domain all the images and pages/posts are broken and return a 404 error. Ive ran search and replace but it doesn't seem to have worked.

www.phoenixworldwideent.com

Answer (score 1):

Manual website migration is very difficult to do. So you can transfer your website in few minutes without any issues using duplicator plugin. you just need to installed the plugin and followed the installation wizard. 
you can read or watch step by step video tutorial [HOW TO CLONE WEBSITE TO NEW HOST USING WORDPRESS DUPLICATOR](http://wpviz.com/copy-website-backup-wordpress-duplicator/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your dashboard, log in, go to settings. 
Change the following:

1. Site Address
2. Wordpress Address

Save. That should work.

Comment: Tried this. Don't know how I managed it but the admin panel is not available anymore

Answer (score 0):

did you try save `permalinks` some times the problem happen because `permalinks` need update 
other point if you can go to old site and use this plugin to move your site agin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there were some issues with the httpd.conf file and httpaccess files. The permalinks and database details were correct. I got this outsourced in the end so not 100% sure what the issue was but I shall update this post with more info when I get it :)